# Data type mismatch in criteria expression for number field in ACCESS 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, windows-forms-designer

I've following two tables with their fields:

```
invoice - invcID (PK), bank, bankFee
invoiceDetails - incDetails (PK), Section, Description, invcID (FK with type number)
```

Following is the query that I am using to insert data into both tables.

```
INSERT INTO invoice([bank], [bankFee]) VALUES (@bank,@bankFee)
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conection);
command.Parameters.Add("@bank",txtBank.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@bankFee",txtBankFee.Text);
int invoiceID = (int)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

INSERT INTO invoiceDetails ([section], [description],[invcID]) VALUES (@section,@description,@invcID)
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, conection);
command.Parameters.Add("@section",txtSection.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@description",txtDescription.Text);
command.Parameters.Add("@invcID",invoiceID);
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The first query runs fine but the second one throws exception of type mismatch. I tried with `DMax()`but still I am facing the exception `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`

**UPDATE**
 Here in following is the table structure

```
table - invoiceID
invcID - Primary Key - data type auto number
bank - data type text
bankFee - data type text

table - invoiceDetails incDetails - Primary Key - data type auto
number Section - data type text Description - data type text InvcID -
foreign key - data type number
```

I am able to get invoice id of latest added invoice. But still I got datatype mismatch error.

```
 double invoiceID = (double)command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 long invoiceID = (long)command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any help?

Comment: What are the values being provided to the statement through the textboxes?

Comment: Every value passed through text box is a string except the invoiceID that is generated when invoice gets created and I got exception for the invoiceID only

Comment: Shouldn't the first statement be `INSERT INTO invoice`?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia, updated

Comment: What are the data types in access for those columns? One seems to not be a string type OR unable to convert from a string to a number maybe based on punctuation? $., in the text value

Comment: both PKs' are auto number, invcID that is FK is number and its field size is Long Integer. The datatype of rest of the fields is text.

Comment: I also tried to cast the invoice id with double and long but no luck. I mean I did following but it don't solve my problem: double invoiceID = (double)command.ExecuteNonQuery(); and also with long, long invoiceID = (long)command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Something seems wrong, as you don't have (here) any _criteria expression_.

Comment: I've updated the question with table strucutre and what I tried to get invoice ID of invoice that is added currently.